# What are the commands to configure Xbee for Arduino upload?

Tags: upload, arduino, xbee

I would like to upload  to arduino uno using my xbee radio but can't seem to get it working. I have configured the xbee to send and receive serials okay, so what am I missing? Why does upload fail?

I used xctu to set the baud rate to 115200 and broadcast mode on the xbee connected to my pc. Same on uno and used a test sketch to send any received serial data from the arduino to the xbee.

When I type in xctu I get back what I types so I know that came from the arduino

Thank you

Comment: Can you please add some more details? What exactly did you configure and how...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is more to it than that. The upload needs to reset the Arduino. The xbee on the uno has not got the power to do this and is also not usually connected to the reset pin by default.

The best solution is to get an Arduino Fio which has the facility built into the hardware. With the uno you will need to hook up some extra electronics but that is quite a simple job.

Once you have your hardware in good state then you will need to use xctu to apply these settings. The setting will be the same as used by the Fio... http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardFioProgramming

This article seems to put together the required xbee commands and the hardware
http://www.faludi.com/itp_coursework/meshnetworking/XBee/XBee_program_Arduino_wireless.html